# Скрыть все блоки в контейнере кроме одного с указанным id и классом

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Доброго времени!
имеется такой HTML

```
<div id="pescont">
    <div class="personajeinl" id="perc1"onclick="javascript:selectperson ('1');"></div>
    <div class="hidrad"></div>
    <div class="personajeinl" id="perc2"onclick="javascript:selectperson ('2');"></div>
    <div class="hidrad"></div>  
    <div class="personajeinl" id="perc3"onclick="javascript:selectperson ('3');"></div>
    <div class="hidrad"></div>  

</div>
```

в блоке с id pescont может быть любое количество блоков и одни из них имеют класс hidrad или id начинающиеся с perc и оканчивающееся цифрой. задача при клике на один из блоков скрывать все остальные кроме кликнутого и блоков с классом hidrad. Пробовал сделать такую функцию но она почему то не работает

```
function selectperson (id) {

$('#pescont *[id != "perc'+id+'"] [class != "hidrad"]').hide();


}
```

В нее передается цифра выбранного блока, но видимо я где то ошибся подскажите что тут не так?

Comment: все ли дивы которые надо скрыть имеют класс _personajeinl_? или этот класс может отсутствовать на некоторых дивах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function selectperson (element) {
  $('.personajeinl').each(function(){
    if (element != this)
      $(this).hide();
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pescont">
    <div class="personajeinl" id="perc1"onclick="javascript:selectperson (this);">1</div>
    <div class="hidrad">22</div>
    <div class="personajeinl" id="perc2"onclick="javascript:selectperson (this);">1</div>
    <div class="hidrad">22</div>  
    <div class="personajeinl" id="perc3"onclick="javascript:selectperson (this);">1</div>
    <div class="hidrad">22</div>  

</div>
```

Как вариант. А то что у вас написано, то неправильный селектор. Для селектора надо было использовать `$("#pescont > div:not('.hidrad')")` например.

Comment: `$(this)[0]`? серьезно?

Comment: не :) На скоро написал не подумав. Хех) поправил..

Comment: @Grundy а можно ли добавить какой то эфект и можно ли сюде его как то строить? попробовал arr[i].fadeOut(); но видимо это вобще не вариант так обращаться

Comment: @dantelol, без знания что такое `arr` не могу ничего сказать, если это объект jQuery, То нет нужды выбирать по индексу - вызывай сразу `arr.fadeOut`

Answer (score 1):

```js
function selectperson (item) {
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("personajeinl");
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  arr[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  item.style.display = "";
}
```

```css
.personajeinl{
border:2px solid red;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="pescont">
    <div class="personajeinl" id="perc1"onclick="selectperson(this)">1111</div>
    <div class="hidrad"></div>
    <div class="personajeinl" id="perc2"onclick="selectperson(this)">2222</div>
    <div class="hidrad"></div>  
    <div class="personajeinl" id="perc3"onclick="selectperson(this)">3333</div>
    <div class="hidrad"></div>  

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Внесу свои 5 копеек, в противовес громоздкости - однострочник
Ну и плюс, разные решения дают больше знаний `(=`

```
function selectperson(item){
    $('.personajeinl').eq(item-1).siblings('.personajeinl').hide()
}
 //Выбираем нужный нам див из массива дивов с классом `personajeinl`
 //Выбираем "братьев" - все элементы того же родителя, за исключением исходного
 //у которых имеется класс `personajeinl`
 //каждый скрываем
```

Comment: вот только непонятно что делает приведенный однострочник.

Comment: @Grundy теперь все поэтапно расписано. Мне казалось, синтаксис достаточно самодокументирован тут

Comment: Без html для которого этот код должен применяться - все еще не полный. Для разметки из вопроса - этот код работает не так как ожидалось

Comment: Ну хотя бы так.

Comment: @Grundy проверил специально с разметкой из вопроса; единственный минус - не увидел, что там итерация пунктов начинается с 1,
уже поправил. В остальном все работает как и ожидалось